# Latex Table in Exam Class

Tags: tables, longtable, exam

I'm trying to add Question Type : Match the Pairs using EXAM Class use code mentioned below :  [FYI: I'm converting HTML Table into Latex table. I'm using pdflatex to get pdf from tex file mentioned below.]

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\medskip\par}
\marksnotpoints
\bracketedpoints
\pointsdroppedatright
\qformat{Q. \thequestion: \thequestiontitle\hfill\thepoints}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubpart}{\arabic{subsubpart}}
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\arabic{choice}}
\runningheadrule
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheader{Competitive Examination}{}{}
\firstpagefooter{}{Page \thepage}{}
\runningfooter{}{Page \thepage}{}
\footrule
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\Alph{partno}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} {\centering \textbf{\Large{Dummy Value}}} \end{center}
\small{ABCD1234} \hspace*{\fill}
\small{TERMINAL EXAMINATION} \hspace*{\fill}
\small{Marks: 60}
\newline
\small{SSC-SET1} \hspace*{\fill}
\small{Science (Ch - 1,2,3)} \hspace*{\fill}
\small{2\textonehalf Hours}
\newline
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} 
\begin{center} {\centering \textbf{SECTION A}} \end{center}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Match the Pairs}[10]
\begin{table}[ht] \begin{tabular}{l l l} \hline \hline 
 A & 
 B & 
\\
 \ 1) Why this text is dummy over here & 
 \ a) there is not dummy text & 
\\
 \ 2) THis is one word & 
 \ b) THis is not the correct word & 
\\
 \ 3) This is dummy value al dfadf adf adfasdf \ ddfakdfaasdf .\  & 
 \ c) values are here for all fasdf ad asdfasdkfad.\  & 
\\
 \ 4) asd fads adsfkaj dkladjsflkadsf asdfa skdlj, asdfasdasdfasdfa & 
 \ d) adjfklasd fasldfjasdlkfjasdlkfadsflkja sdflkjasd;lfkjasd;lfkja;sldkfjals;dk\  & 
\\
 \ 5) asdfasdfjas;dlfkjaslkdalkdsjf;alksdjfasdklfads & 
 \ e) adjfklasdjfa;lksdjf;alskdjf;alskdjf;alksdjf;laksdjf;alksdfj;alksdfja;lksdfja;lksdfja;lskdfj;alksdjfalksdfjasdklfjas;dlfja;sdlkfalkdjfa;lkdsjf;alksdfaldfja;lsdkfja;lsdkjf;alskdfj;aldkjf;alksdjfalksddddddfajsdlkfja;lsdkjf ;alsdjf ;asdjf; ajdf;l j;asdlfj ;alkdjsf;laksejriaeidkl ja;dlkfja;slkdfj a;ldskfja;sdikdfka dof asdf asdfk;lajsd;flkaj d;lkfajsd;lfk ja;dsfj ;alskdjf; lkadsjf;alksdjf; alsdfkja;lskdjf;alsdjf;alsdkjf;alskdjf\  & 
\\
\hline \end{tabular} \label{table:nonlin} \end{table} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Generated output is mentioned below [image]

I'm facing two problems in this code :

- Match the pair table is coming above question title
- If there is
  longer word or more text, it's going outside pagewidth

Can you please give me direction to solve these errors?

Comment: I would suggest *using* the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) as you've already included in your preamble and use `\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}...\end{tabularx}` to set the "match the pairs table. This will allow for proper line breaking while also filling the text block width.

Comment: Now both issues are solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some more to add on Phil and Werner's answer: first, for list structure, you should consider using `enumerate` environment; second, even with `tabularx` LaTeX will still have some trouble handling extremely long word which had appeared in your example, in this case you can either use `\hyphenation{...}` to manually set up hyphenation or use `\seqsplit{...}` provided by `seqsplit` package. Now here is a demonstration:

```
\usepackage{seqsplit}
```

Here I skip the preamble for it's too long

```
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Match the Pairs}[10]
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\hline
\hline 
A
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi})}
\item Why this text is dummy over here
\item THis is one word
\item This is dummy value al dfadf adf adfasdf \ ddfakdfaasdf .
\item asd fads adsfkaj dkladjsflkadsf asdfa skdlj, asdfasdasdfasdfa
\item asdfasdfjas;dlfkjaslkdalkdsjf;alksdjfasdklfads
\end{enumerate}
& 
B
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\item there is not dummy text
\item THis is not the correct word
\item values are here for all fasdf ad asdfasdkfad.
\item adjfklasd fasldfjasdlkfjasdlkfadsflkja sdflkjasd;lfkjasd;lfkja;sldkfjals;dk
\item
\seqsplit{adjfklasdjfa;lksdjf;alskdjf;alskdjf;alksdjf;laksdjf;alksdfj;alksdfja;lksdfja;lksdfja;lskdfj;alksdjfalksdfjasdklfjas;dlfja;sdlkfalkdjfa;lkdsjf;alksdfaldfja;lsdkfja;lsdkjf;alskdfj;aldkjf;alksdjfalksddddddfajsdlkfja;lsdkjf ;alsdjf ;asdjf; ajdf;l j;asdlfj ;alkdjsf;laksejriaeidkl ja;dlkfja;slkdfj a;ldskfja;sdikdfka dof asdf asdfk;lajsd;flkaj d;lkfajsd;lfk ja;dsfj ;alskdjf; lkadsjf;alksdjf; alsdfkja;lskdjf;alsdjf;alsdkjf;alskdjf}
\end{enumerate}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

and its result:

[image]

---

## Update

After thinking a while about your new request I came up a way to mimic the `enumerate` environment with `tabularx`. First of all, we need to define two new counters:

```
\newcounter{counterA}
\setcounter{counterA}{0}

\newcounter{counterB}
\setcounter{counterB}{0}
```

Then we need two new column types:

```
\newcolumntype{A}{
@{
\stepcounter{counterA}
\hspace{\itemindent}
\arabic{counterA})
\hspace{\labelsep}
\vspace{\itemsep}
}X}

\newcolumntype{B}{
@{
\stepcounter{counterB}
\hspace{\itemindent}
\alph{counterA})
\hspace{\labelsep}
\vspace{\itemsep}
}X}
```

Now let's check out the code (again this is only the crucial part):

```
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Match the Pairs}[10]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{AB}
\hline
\hline 

\multicolumn{2}{l}{A\hspace{216.46775pt}B}\\[\topsep]

Why this text is dummy over here &
there is not dummy text\\

THis is one word & 
THis is not the correct word \\

This is dummy value al dfadf adf adfasdf \ ddfakdfaasdf . & 
values are here for all fasdf ad asdfasdkfad.\\

asd fads adsfkaj dkladjsflkadsf asdfa skdlj, asdfasdasdfasdfa & 
adjfklasd fasldfjasdlkfjasdlkfadsflkja sdflkjasd;lfkjasd;lfkja;sldkfjals;dk\\

asdfasdfjas;dlfkjaslkdalkdsjf;alksdjfasdklfads &
\seqsplit{adjfklasdjfa;lksdjf;alskdjf;alskdjf;alksdjf;laksdjf;alksdfj;alksdfja;lksdfja;lksdfja;lskdfj;alksdjfalksdfjasdklfjas;dlfja;sdlkfalkdjfa;lkdsjf;alksdfaldfja;lsdkfja;lsdkjf;alskdfj;aldkjf;alksdjfalksddddddfajsdlkfja;lsdkjf ;alsdjf ;asdjf; ajdf;l j;asdlfj ;alkdjsf;laksejriaeidkl ja;dlkfja;slkdfj a;ldskfja;sdikdfka dof asdf asdfk;lajsd;flkaj d;lkfajsd;lfk ja;dsfj ;alskdjf; lkadsjf;alksdjf; alsdfkja;lskdjf;alsdjf;alsdkjf;alskdjf}\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{questions}
```

that will give us:

[image]

As you can see, what we got is quite similar to the implemented `enumerate` environment we previously have, and this time we also have nice vertical alignment. However, this method still has some imperfections, for instances:

1. There are some mysterious indentation caused by `seqsplit` I don't quite understand.
2. In the first line of the table,`\topsep` is from the `list` environment. I tried to put it into column definition with `\ifnum` but failed :P
3. `216.46775pt` is manually calculated `0.5\linewidth-\columnsep`, I don't know how to make `calc` work inside a table so I didn't use it.

et cetera et cetera.

Comment: Thanks Francis for answers. Basically I'm converting HTML table into Latex. Currently I'm reading TR TD in as sequence and generating latex code, that's reason i'm getting one extra column at the end. Now using tabularx i'm controlling width of last column (to make it invisible). Is there any way to achieve output mentioned above like : \item Why this text is dummy over here & \item there is not dummy text (next to each other) ?

Comment: @PawanMude not sure if I get it, so you want separate items be on the same line?

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem of the table appearing above the question title, you should not have your `tabular` environment inside of a `table` environment.  The `table` environment is a floating environment, which isn't really what you want anyway, since you want the table to appear exactly where you put it, i.e., you don't want it to float to a different location.

Comment: I've removed table and problem of "Match the pair table coming above question title" is solved . Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: Add my `tabularx` suggestion to complete the solution.

Comment: Now both issues are solved. Thanks for your help.